# ¿Cómo coloco datos para rellenar?

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

Buen día, estoy haciendo un trabajo para la facultad sobre una base de datos en Microsoft Access. Quiero que se vea bien pero para eso quiero generar varios registros y tengo varias tablas para registrar. Mi pregunta es si existe una manera de añadir automáticamente datos a una tabla, respetando los formatos de la casilla y las relaciones entre las tablas. Por ejemplo, en la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero colocar registros aleatorios apretando simplemente un botón. El número de orden es auto numeración, se llena solo. El código de la pieza tiene que contener números no mayores a 30. Tanto el código del paciente como del odontólogo tienen que llenarse con números existentes en otras tablas (y si no se puede eso, que sean números en un rango que pueda elegir, como de 1 a 10). La fecha de ingreso tiene que llenarse con el formato fecha. La observación no hace falta llenarla pero si se puede mejor. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Se podría hacer con una macro desde VBA o importando los datos desde eExcel masivamente si los tienes en una plantilla adaptados. Pero el tiempo de diseño de ambas cosas, salvo que tengas experiencia, es bastante amplio, así que dependiendo del volumen de registros a crear puede compensarte o no.

Comment: Supongamos que quiero llenar con 30 registros a una tabla ¿Cómo sería el diseño de la macro en Access para que me coloque 30 registros al azar en esa tabla?

Comment: Me temo que la respuesta es amplia. Básicamente, estás pidiendo un desarrollo completo desde cero, sin aportar nada de código. Deberías intentar hacer algo y preguntar solo partes concretas. Pero la idea sería un bucle que se repita 30 veces y en cada vuelta meta los valores aleatorios que te interesan.